# Typescript partial key mapping

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I'm trying to create a generic type that would map the keys using template literals. In general i just want to created a nested type from the list of commaseparated keys:

```
type TFoobar = "address" | "year" | "owner.age" | "owner.address.street";

const foobar: DotToType<TFooBar> = {
    address: true,
    owner: {
        age: true,
        address: {
            street: true
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried implementing it like so:

```
type DotToType<keys extends string> = {
    [Key in keys]: Key extends `${infer Parent}.${infer Leaf}`
        ? {[key in Parent]: DotToType<Leaf>}
        : {[k in Key]: boolean}
}[keys];
```

And while it does have a proper typing, it makes the properties optional (at least one is required, but there is nothing that enforces they are all present)

```
const foobar: DotToType<TFooBar> = {
    address: true,
}; //valid, shouldnt be

const foobar: DotToType<TFooBar> = {
    owner: {
        age: true
    },
}; //valid, shouldnt be

const foobar: DotToType<TFooBar> = {
    address: true,
    year: false,
    owner: {
        age: true,
        address: {
            street: true
        }
    }
}; //valid
```

I also tried doing it like this:

```
type DotToType<keys extends string> = {
    [Key in keys as Key extends `${infer Parent}.${infer Leaf}` ? Parent : Key]:
    Key extends `${infer Parent}.${infer Leaf}` ? DotToType<Leaf> : boolean
};
```

And while it does enforce fields, it stops working if I have multiple paths for the same object.

```
const foobar: DotToType<"address" | "year" | "owner.address.street"> = {
    "address": true,
    "year": true,
    owner: {
        address: {
            street: true
        }
    }
}; // this works fine


const foobar: DotToType<"address" | "year" | "owner.address.street" | "owner.age"> = {
    "address": true,
    "year": true,
    owner: {
        address: {
            street: true
        }
    }
}; // this only allows the first `owner.{Leaf}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial code produces a union, which is why the properties are optional:

```ts
type DotToType<keys extends string> = {
    [Key in keys]: Key extends `${infer Parent}.${infer Leaf}`
        ? {[key in Parent]: DotToType<Leaf>}
        : {[k in Key]: boolean}
}[keys];

type MyType = DotToType<TFoobar>

// produces:

type MyType = {
    address: boolean;
} | {
    year: boolean;
} | {
    owner: {
        age: boolean;
    };
} | {
    owner: {
        address: {
            street: boolean;
        };
    };
}
```

You can use the following:

```ts
type TFoobar = "address" | "year" | "owner.age" | "owner.address.street";

type BeforeDot<K extends string> = K extends `${infer Parent}.${infer _}` ? Parent : K;
type ChildrenAfterDot<K extends string, P extends string> = K extends `${P}.${infer $Leaf}` ? $Leaf : never;


type DotToType<keys extends string> = {
    [Key in BeforeDot<keys>]: Key extends keys
        ? boolean
        : DotToType<ChildrenAfterDot<keys, Key>>
};

type MyType = DotToType<TFoobar>

// produces: 
type MyType = {
    address: boolean;
    year: boolean;
    owner: DotToType<"age" | "address.street">;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgYgewQIwIYCcoF4oCJUAmB6EAzqblAD54gQaU24IDuAdhOgHSoDmEjPKw7dCxMqS6lgJCMFwBuAFBLQkKACEIAMwQkAIgmAAeANJQIAD2AQ2BUlGnoAlm14A+bFHNWbdhwAGACQA3q7anFAAChi2wAC+XKHhkQD68QFQAPzRsWzAUABc3spq0ADCABbOADbibACC2jbohiY+1rb2jjKuvAA00Rad-j0ubp44HX7dwSFRiclsEZhBADL02hnZUOubRVAcAG6cyiplUG0wCDDgEMYA1hAgDr5dDk59k1AhSlD-UAA2qZnlBXJodHoIG1Hs9SO4ALrFEEgYYzBxPF5-AE4nLIJA1ehsbE4-7FK43O7GKq1epNFowzGkQYo9zuJTxM4XACyIFu6hwFP593gSDQ6HZSgAxgg2NIoLoUBgAAzkozXYXGfBEEjkQS4OgMahCdicHg6iRSGQQOS4b6-HHa8R64oyACuEH6JNo9HQuFd6A9Xpxwk4xQdpP+Yl1pHD3sj-ycNuAAY98YB8W9mc5UAA9LmoMBqg4WHoHg5tK4ICppbL5YrxQBGNXADVUp0x-WGv3G5im0QW8hW2TyXuh0T8O1eCP-DsSf2FwOe70G30L93LkP9uMJqDRiQ73cApNyVPV3eZnHZhR5gt8aDOBwAW0fpD6g1Qr0skClNgIQA)